# jQuery Mobile - Load images via ajax AFTER page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile app that's phonegap powered with jQuery Mobile running. I'm needing the ability to load potentially large images but having the page attempt to load the images on page load without any notification as to that's what it's doing makes the page appear to be unfunctional and broken. So I need to inform the user via a loading image that there is an image being loaded. I tried using this script which I've used in dozens of other web apps but it's not working in jQuery Mobile:

```
var img = new Image();    
  // wrap our new image in jQuery, then:
  $(img)
    // once the image has loaded, execute this code
    .load(function () {
      // set the image hidden by default    
      $(this).hide();       
      // with the holding div #loader, apply:
      $('#container')
        // remove the loading class (so no background spinner), 
        // then insert our image
        .append(this);      
      // fade our image in to create a nice effect
      $(this).fadeIn();
    })      
    // if there was an error loading the image, react accordingly
    .error(function () {
      // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
    })      
    // *finally*, set the src attribute of the new image to our image
    .attr('src', 'http://somedomain.com/largeimagetobeloaded.png');
```

As I mentioned this has worked in many other locations with out any problems but I can't seem to get it to load. Fiddler doesn't seem to show any request being fired off by the application and I've tried $('#container').page() and $('#container').trigger('create')

Can anyone give any pointers as to how to load an image via ajax into a div in a jQuery Mobile page?